# I have applied for leave of absence today/ for today

Tags: prepositions, semantic-roles

1. *I have applied for leave of absence for today.*
2. *I have applied for leave of absence today.*

I think there is some difference in meaning between the two sentences.

I think the sentence 1 means specifically that I applied for leave of absence for oneday that is today.

The second sentence means I have applied for  leave of absence today. It does not specify whether the leave of absence is for today or for some more days.

I would like to know whether I am correct or wrong.

I herewith attach the link which I have searched.

https://textranch.com/79386/i-have-applied-for-leave/or/i-have-applied-leave/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are right!

> I have applied for *a casual leave* today

Here, it means that today is the day of 'application.'

Nevertheless,

> I have applied for *a casual leave* **for** the next Monday

...would mean that you are not coming on Monday.

It'll be a little ambiguous though *fun* if you are applying for leave (for Monday) today!

> I have applied for *a casual leave* **for** the next Monday, today!

Comment: .is The article a before leave is necessary?

Comment: Of course, it's a *countable* noun in this context.

Comment: '***A** casual leave **day***' but '*casual leave*' for an unspeficied amount.

Comment: @Smock in the given context, putting *day* is redundant! So, I am taking *a leave* works. You don't need to add a 'day.'

Comment: Maybe it's just me being a native BrE speaker, but we would never just say '*taking a leave*' without it being '*a leave (sth)*'. For us it's '*taking leave / taking casual leave / taking annual leave*'. We only add the **a** when it's a leave (something): '*taking a leave day / taking a casual leave day / taking a leave of absence*'